# iGoogle, netvibes etc. alike script or ideas?

Tags: php, javascript, portal

I have get an very good idea of making a social dashbord, like iGoogle/netvibes. But I would like to do it my self.
So my question is, are there a script in php, that are build that I can begin with if not is there possible to use Google Gadget API or any other alike API?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [Google's Gadget API](http://code.google.com/apis/igoogle/).

Also take a look at this SlideShar Presentation, [How to Build Your Own Social Media Dashboard On A Shoestring Budget](http://www.slideshare.net/webmeticsguru/how-to-build-your-own-social-media-monitoring-dashboard-on-a-shoestring)

Here's an article about building with netvibes, [Build A Social Media Network With Netvibes](http://blog.socialsourcecommons.org/2010/05/building-a-social-media-dashboard-with-netvibes/)

If you get stuck anywhere, please do ask, we'd be happy to help.